# Reference dynamically named column in the same pipe?

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to make a simple function that groups by group, summarises a variable and mutates the result.

```
fun <- function(df, group, var) {
  df %>%
    group_by(group) %>%
    summarise(num_var = n_distinct(var)) %>%
    mutate(perc_var = num_var / sum(num_var))
}
```

I would like to dynamically replace the word "var" with the name of the column. I can get it to work as far as the summarise:

```
fun <- function(df, group, var) {
  df %>% 
    group_by({{group}}) %>% 
    summarise('num_{{var}}' := n_distinct({{var}}))
}
```

But I'm having trouble referencing the newly created num_var column in the mutate.

Expected output:

```
df %>%
  fun(category, account)
```

```
category    num_account    perc_account
```

Comment: Based on your function definition there is only one variable so what is `perc_account` here in your desired output?

Comment: It's the variable created in the mutate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this :

```
library(dplyr)

fun <- function(df, group, var) {
  col <- paste0('num_', deparse(substitute(var)))
  df %>% 
    group_by({{group}}) %>% 
    summarise(!!col := n_distinct({{var}})) %>%
    mutate('perc_{{var}}' := prop.table(.data[[col]]))
}

mtcars %>% fun(cyl, gear)


#    cyl num_gear perc_gear
#  <dbl>    <int>     <dbl>
#1     4        3     0.375
#2     6        3     0.375
#3     8        2     0.25
```

Comment: Almost - I also need "perc_gear", not "perc_var".